# How to combine two rxjs streams where one depends on another

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

I have two streams. One receiving events for projects (*ProjectCreated*, *ClientIdChanged*,*ProjectNameChanged*).

The second receiving events for clients (*ClientCreated*,*ClientNameChanged*)

Here is the idea. I want to start receiving events for projects and then when I figure out what projects I do have, getting clientId from specific project events: *ProjectCreated*, *ProjectNameChanged*
I want to start a client stream for those client ids.

So, if I have **projectA** and **projectB** with **clientIdA** and **clientIdB** I want to tell to client stream I want events for those client ids **[ClienetIdA,clientIdB]**
In reality this is webSocket and I would call **clientSubject.next([clientIdA,clientIdB])**.

I always have to send all client ids. For example if I got event *ProjectCreated* I can not just send clientIdC, but **[ClientIdA,ClientIdB,ClientIdC]**
Where to store previous clientId values (**clientIdA** and **ClientIdB** in this case)?

I use React, I could use Rect state but I would like to avoid it if it is posible.
I was thinking about scan operator on project stream that keeps client ids and on change detection calls **clientSubject.next(newClientIds)** but I see two drawbacks here:

1. It would be a bit clamsy due to keeeping track of client ids but also passing regular project events down the stream but it is not major issue
2. If client stream get reconnect I do not know how to resend client ids

I am struggling to figure out what is the best way (pattern) to combine those two rxjs streams.

What would be the best way to combine them?

Zlaja

Comment: I've solved it by a custom operator.  This article helps me https://netbasal.com/creating-custom-operators-in-rxjs-32f052d69457.